# Import csv without escape quotes javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have the CSV file like below,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCmfd.png

I read the file data using the method "readAsText" or "readAsBinaryString";

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),

readFile = function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;

    };
    reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);
};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);

reader.result will give the following result,

Version,IP Address,Hostname,data 1235FDRRG,A1,7.0(3)(2),1.1.1.1,admin," 
{""1"":""rollno"",""2"":""serialnumber""}"
```

Here, escaping quotes comes `{""1"":""rollno"",""2"":""serialnumber""}`.

How can I import the CSV file without escaping quotes?

I want the data like `{"1":"rollno","2":"serialnumber"}`

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace that quotes by using regex.

> reader.result.replace(/(\"\")/g,'"').slice(1,-1);

after that you will get same result as you want -

{"1":"rollno","2":"serialnumber"}

Comment: var str = '"{""1"":""rollno"",""2"":""serialnumber""}"';
str.replace(/(\"\")/g,'"');

Getting the following result,
""{"1":"rollno","2":"serialnumber"}""

Comment: It's not the expected result.

Comment: use this - str.replace(/(\"\")/g,'"').slice(1,-1);